# How to find previous value in dataframe column based on another columns value

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a data frame containing football matches with columns for:

- Matchday (date)
- Home Team
- Away Team

I want to calculate how long it has been since a team last played. That means I have to find the latest appearance of *Team* and get the date, i.e. Matchday.

I really have no idea how to do it, except maybe converting the structure to a long format. But as for matching based on team and grabbing the matchday I am lost.

Current structure:

| Matchday | Team | Home_Away |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-05 | Arsenal FC | Away |
| 2022-08-05 | Crystal Palace | Home |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-08-13 | Arsenal FC | Home |
| 2022-08-13 | Leicester City | Away |

So I want a column indicating rest days basically:

| Matchday | Team | Home_Away | Rest_Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-05 | Arsenal FC | Away | NA |
| 2022-08-05 | Crystal Palace | Home | NA |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-08-07 | Leicester City | Home | NA |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-08-13 | Arsenal FC | Home | 8 |
| 2022-08-13 | Leicester City | Away | 6 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort the dataframe by team and date (date in ascending order). Then you create a column with the lagged value of date within the Team. For instance with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- 
    data %>%
    group_by(Team) %>%
    mutate(rest_days = Matchday - dplyr::lag(Matchday, n = 1, default = NA))
```

I could not check if that works exactly in that manner, but the idea (sort, group and then lag) should work..